# asynchronously load styles using nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

How to asynchronously load styles to the site. Or insert style in the footer?

I use nuxt: 2.0.0

I try:

- add plugin in webpack: async-stylesheet-webpack-plugin. But, prerender in nuxt add styles.
- create module. But how to remove old styles?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I develop module:

```js
const STYLE_REGEXP = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="(.+?)">'
const STYLE_TEMPLATE = '<link rel="preload" href="$1" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel=\'stylesheet\'">' +
  '<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="$1"></noscript>'

module.exports = async function asyncCss (options) {
  this.nuxt.hook('render:route', renderRouteHandle.bind(this))
}

async function renderRouteHandle (url, result) {
  result.html = result.html.replace(
    new RegExp(STYLE_REGEXP, 'g'), STYLE_TEMPLATE)
}
```

Helped for me https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2822